# Working with sub-objects in handlbars

Tags: templates, handlebars.js

How does one work with sub-objects in handlebars? I have the following data:

```
{
    name: "first-name-field",
    spec: {
        label: {
            text: "First Name:"
        },
        input: {
            type: "text",
            value: ""
        }
    },
    template: "field"
}
```

The field template it is referring to is as follows:

```
<div class="label-wrapper">
    <label>
        {{specs.label.text}}
    </label>
</div>
<div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="{{specs.input.type}}" value="{{specs.input.value}}" />
</div>
```

The label section builds but the input section never appears. Im assuming this is because the scope has already changes. I have tried the `../` prefix as well,  but it never sees to move back to the parent object.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have done some spell mistake. In template "specs" and in dict "spec"

Otherwise your code is working fine. I have tested your code screen short is attached. [image]